# LINQ multiple list join

Tags: c#, linq

I'm learning LINQ and I tried to set up a complexer situation to manage with LINQ. Well... I'm stuck.

What I set up are 3 classes

Class class:

```
class Class
{
    public int Number { get; private set; }

    public Class(int number)
    {
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

Teacher class:

```
class Teacher
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public int Class { get; set; }

    public Teacher(string name, int Class)
    {
        Name = name;
        this.Class = Class;
    }
}
```

Student class:

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Class { get; set; }

    public Student(string name, int Class)
    {
        Name = name;
        this.Class = Class;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is joining these 3 Classes together to get a list of the school class containing the teacher and their students.

I tried like:

```
var classWithTeacherAndStudent =
            from Class in classes
            join Teacher in teacher
                on Class.Number equals Teacher.Class
            let teacherClass = new {Class, Teacher}
            join student in students
                on teacherClass.Class.Number equals student.Class
                into entireClass
            select new
            {

            };
```

There are many Class, Teacher and Student Objects ready in lists.

Comment: What exactly do you want your result to be?  Can you show some examples of what is in your lists and the desired results?

Comment: It seems like you have the joins right - where are you stuck?  Are you just looking for the syntax to output the fields?  Do you want a flat list or nested groups?

Comment: @DStanley I'm stuck putting it into nested groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join seems to be correct. You can just select all the values to an anonymous type, so each entry has a class, its teacher, and all of its students.

```
var classWithTeacherAndStudent =
from Class in classes
join Teacher in teacher
    on Class.Number equals Teacher.Class
let teacherClass = new { Class, Teacher }
join student in students
    on teacherClass.Class.Number equals student.Class
    into entireClass
select new
{
    teacherClass.Teacher, teacherClass.Class, entireClass
};

foreach (var entry in classWithTeacherAndStudent)
{
    Console.WriteLine("teacher: {0}, class: {1}", entry.Teacher.Name, entry.Class.Number);
    foreach (var student in entry.entireClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize that my "entireClass" list was only containing students. I got it now